# How to update value of a specific column in the first row of a SQL database table

Tags: sql, case

I have below records in my SQL Server 2019 database table:

| ID | NAME | IsDefault |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Closed | 0 |
| 2 | Closed | 0 |

and on this table, I am writing a query to update the IsDefault column based on the value of Name column. If there are no values like ('Active','Open') in Name column, I need to update the IsDefault value to '1' as it is the first row of the table (note: I cant take in this record using ID column)

So far, I have written this query to accomplish this:

```
UPDATE [Catalogue].[schema].[table_name] 
SET IsDefault = case 
when (SELECT top 1 t.Rwnumber FROM 
  (SELECT isdefault,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [isdefault]) AS Rwnumber 
   from [Catalogue].[schema].[table_name] 
) t  ) = '1'
then '1'
else '0' end
```

Here, I am essentially trying to update the record Rwnumber = 1 with '1' however, my query results in updating both the record.

Can anyone tell me the logical issue behind this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of using the window function `row_number()`, a simple query can be used :

```
UPDATE table_name SET isdefault = 1 
WHERE ID = (SELECT top 1 ID FROM table_name ORDER BY ID)
```